# Running Docker Container outside of VS debug

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio

Scenario:
Create a new ASP API Dotnet project selecting the docker container option
Build the project - the swagger page shows and is functioning. The log output also shows that the ports are listening
All good so far.

Stop debugging
Start the Container that was build in the above step.
The logs are correct but cannot browse to swagger page..

I think this is related to https(???) but disabled it in code and in the launchSetting.json

```
    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    //if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    //{
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    //}

    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();
```

I am certain I am not the only one that has experienced this. Any suggestions?

I also tried Docker build... and it built and I get the logs but cant browse to http://localhost:32751/swagger/index.html

Using VS2022 - all the latest stuff
Running all this on windows but the generated docker is Linux (as I would expect).
Something is wrong with mappings or kestrel interference or ...

Don't know how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

The image built for debugging (<project name>:dev) is optimized for debugging and relies on volume mounts to run your service ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022#debugging) if you're interested). To get an image you can test locally you can right-click on your Dockerfile and select Build Image:
[image]

Update: Just noticed the URI you were trying. The URI `~/swagger/index.html` is usually only available when the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `Development`. You have the check commented out, but is there a chance you didn't rebuild the full image with that change? The other way to check is to run `docker run -P -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development <image name>` to run your image in Development mode which is the way VS activates that feature.

Comment: But it does build an image and the related container but when not debugging the container,  if started independently did not accept endpoints. I also get https error

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile and the output from running your image? I tested on a new Web API project and was able to connect on HTTP when running using the command I just added. The HTTPS port from my image didn't work, but that's expected as there are additional steps to configure a certificate outside VS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-8.0